# How to find the largest value within a parameter using linked list?

Tags: c++, function, class, linked-list

I am tasked with implementing a new class function called `bool List::largest_value(int &largest)` within a given `class List`. The instruction is:

> If the list is not empty, put the largest value in the largest
> parameter and return true.  If the list is empty, return false.

My question is, how do I find the largest value within a parameter?
Here is what I have so far for `bool List::largest_value(int &largest)`:

```
// Fill in the functions at the bottom of this file
//
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

// on some machines member variables are not automatically initialized to 0
List::List()
{
    m_head = NULL;
}

// delete all Nodes in the list
// since they are dynamically allocated using new, they won't go away
// automatically when the list is deleted
// Rule of thumb: destructor deletes all memory created by member functions
List::~List()
{
    while (m_head)
    {
        Node *tmp = m_head;
        m_head = m_head->m_next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

// always insert at the front of the list
// Note: this works even in the SPECIAL CASE that the list is empty
void List::insert(int value)
{
    m_head = new Node(value, m_head);
}

// iterate through all the Nodes in the list and print each Node
void List::print()
{
    for (Node *ptr = m_head; ptr; ptr = ptr->m_next)
    {
        cout << ptr->m_value << endl;
    }
}

void List::compare(int target, int &less_than, int &equal, int &greater_than)
{
    Node *temp = m_head;
    less_than = 0;
    equal = 0;
    greater_than = 0;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->m_value > target)
        {
            greater_than++;
        }
        else if(temp->m_value < target)
        {
           less_than++;
        }
        else if(temp->m_value == target)
        {
            equal++;
        }

        temp = temp-> m_next;
    }

}

bool List::largest_value(int &largest)
{
   Node *temp = m_head;
   largest = INT_MIN;


    if(temp == NULL)
    {

        return false;
    }


    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->m_value > largest)
        {
            largest = temp->m_value;
        }
        temp = temp->m_next;

    }
    return true;

}
```

Here is the given `class List`:

```
class List
{
    public:
        List();
        ~List();
        void insert(int value); // insert at beginning of list
        void print(); // print all values in the list
        void compare(int target, int &less_than, int &equal, int &greater_than);
        bool largest_value(int &largest);

    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(int value, Node *next)
                {m_value = value; m_next = next;}
                int m_value;
                Node *m_next;
        };
        Node *m_head;
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    List list;
    int value;

    // read values and insert them into list
    while (cin >> value)
    {
      list.insert(value);
    }

    int largest;
    bool result = list.largest_value(largest);

    if (result == false)
    {
        cout << "empty list" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The largest value you entered is:  " <<  largest << endl;
    }
}
```

My code compiles and runs, however I keep receiving the output `empty list`. I honestly have no idea what I need to change in my `bool List::largest_value(int &largest)`function. I am still very new to linked lists. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `while(m_head != NULL)` and `m_head = m_head->m_next;` - bad idea. Don't use the lists head pointer to walk the list. When you're done you will have orphaned (leaked) all the nodes and be left with an empty list. Use a temporary pointer, initially set to the value of `m_head`, to walk the list end to end.

Comment: Doing `return true;` unconditionally in the loop may not be what you want.

Comment: `if(m_head == NULL) { return false; }  while { ... } return true;`

Comment: @WhozCraig okay, should I put `Node *temp = m_head;` ?

Comment: Yes, use `Node *temp = m_head;` and then within the `while` loop, iterate using `temp` and `temp->next`.

Comment: @MikeCAT okay, didn't catch that. I will take it out of the loop

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, I will fill fix that. Thank you for the recommendation

Comment: You need a minimal reproducible example, your code doesn't even compile you need to give us the constructor and destructor....

Comment: Since you are looking for the largest value, when you construct your class, `largest` should be initialized to `INT_MIN`, e.g. `int largest = INT_MIN;` See [Limits of integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits). You will need to include the `<climits>` header. This insures that if all your values are negative values, you will still select the largest.

Comment: @YunfeiChen Okay, I added the complete code

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I initialized `INT_MIN` to `largest` and inserted `Node *temp = m_head;` , however I am still receiving the same output as before

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Never mind, it works now. Thank you very much for your help. That did the trick!

Comment: @Fooji "My question is, how do I find the largest value within a parameter? Here is what I have so far for bool List::largest_value(int &largest):" I am confused it sounds like you want to find the largest value, so why are you returning a bool instead of int or the value??

Comment: @YunfeiChen -- it looks like `int largest = INT_MIN;` will be declared in the scope where the list is also declared. Then a reference is passed as a parameter to `.largest_value(largest);` and if the return is `true`, then `largest` holds the valid list max. Otherwise, it is left as `INT_MIN`.